# Why would I ever use tf.concat instead of tf.stack?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a good reason to use `tf.concat` instead of `tf.stack`? They seem very similar. Is it just to guarantee that the resulting tensor will have the same number of dimensions as the input list of tensors?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Actually, I've misunderstood how `tf.stack` works. If the `axis` parameter is within the range of the existing dimensions, a new axis will be inserted at that index.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.random_normal([1, 3])
t2 = tf.random_normal([1, 3])

tf.stack([t1, t2], axis=1).shape.as_list() == [1, 2, 3]
tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=1).shape.as_list() == [1, 6]
```

Comment: Is there a way to use tf.concat() in some way and emulate the behavior of tf.stack?

Comment: @skadaver I don't think it is good practice to add this type of comment to such an old answer. But the answer to your question is yes. tf.concat only works with existing dimensions, while tf.stack creates a new dimension. You can use tf.expand_dims to create an "extra" dimension of size 1 beforehand, and then use tf.concat on that specific dimension.